# library not found for -lRCTGeolocation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-firebase

Have installed react-native-firebase & and i'am using my project.xcworkspace for getting build on iOS with Xcode that was fine when I installed only auth & core packages. When i installed messaging package I get the error  "library not found for -lRCTGeolocation" anyway. Some could help me?

react-native: 0.60.3
react-native-firebase: 5.5.4

Thansk in advance.

I delete the messaging reference from pod file I delete pods folder & podfile.lock file re installed pods, clean the build but didn't
solved.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The geolocation module isn't a part of the react-native core module anymore since de 0.60 version (cf: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60)

For it, you have to replace with the https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation and delete the RCTGeolocation on the Libraries folder of your xcode project

Comment: What I need to replace?

Answer (score -2):

downgrading react-native version to 0.59.10, deleting pods folder, podfile.lock & my project.xcworkspace and regenerating via pod install fixed my problem

Comment: I'm aware this is not your answer.I did everything but downgrade and it failed to remove the error: `Library not found for -lDoubleConversion`.

I'm aware this is not your answer. I'm adding a comment to help understand the problem.

Comment: i was started my project with version 0.59.10 and upgraded to 0.60 . Linking mechanism change since version 0.60 downgrading version to original version of project.